# Script to replace BS4 -> BS 5 Css, mass rename BootStrap 4 to BootStrap 5 CSS classes

Tags: bootstrap-5

**Bootstrap 4** *has* **over 1500 CSS/Sass classes**, we are prepping for `Bootstrap 5`. I was asked to test which part of the site would break. Since, this is a huge task, can you share how to go about the upgrade migrate process.

How do you achieve this, is there a script or plugin or compliance check on **how to do this upgrade**?

*Back then, from BS 3 to BS4  this was more manageable!* but with 1500 CSS I need help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a Bootstrap 5 Migrate Tool script which scans all pages/templates in a folder and:

- Replaces all the Bootstrap 4 classes with Bootstrap 5 classes.
- Replaces deprecated components (such as `.jumbotron` and `.media`) with the relevant utility classes
- Renames all the data attributes (such as `data-toggle` and `data-target`) to the new bs-prefixed names
- Updates all Bootstrap v4 CDN links (jsdelivr.net, unpkg.com and stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com) to latest version of Bootstrap v5.

It's free and open-source:
https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-5-migrate-tool

Comment: I like this and upvoted, but is there a prompt to give us a summary and any items missed

Comment: Thanks! I've thought about adding a summary and suggestions on items missed and may consider adding that in a future update.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe im a little bit late to the party but you can use this script here.

https://gist.github.com/Juan-escobar94/f76535a1264ac6f7251c643af50c184d

I tested it on a few projects and it went without hurdles. you can change the -i sed output to generate backup files, because it will otherwise edit your files without backup.

Comment: Hello thanks, Can you add some comments below, sorry new to sed. In my case, I have some [additional](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/) custom BS4 classes, and want to change using your script as well. I would like to extend your script and use it, comments would be very helpful thanks

Comment: Sorry, my scripts for better smaller projects.

Comment: I used the linked Gist for my project. It helped, but is missed about half the easy changes. There are quite a few changes beyond easy replacements - just dig through the change list and add the missing easy changes. Also, look up replacements for some of the form classes, there are some simple replacements one can add to the script.

Comment: For smaller projects, since people don't like my other answer. https://properprogramming.com/tools/converters/bootstrap-4-to-bootstrap-5-converter/

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I think I understand your question. If you have a separate css page, go to the html page, and do the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--Bootstrap 4, not 5-->
```

Keep in mind, that the above code is Bootstrap 4, so replace the link with the 5. Anyway, continued:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/yourcss.css">
<!--linking to my CSS page-->
```

So, therefore, you need to check your site in all perspectives, and see what would break using bootstrap 5.

Comment: I am actually looking to _update all the CSS/HTML components_ on _each of my web pages_. Not just a ref. link. thats easy..